# Reformatting Java Source Code, instead of next line use end of line curly braces

Tags: java, string, file, curly-braces

I've been trying to figure out how to implement a problem (linked further down) but, I'm hitting a wall.

Basically I have to reformat source code that uses next line curly braces to end of line curly braces. For some reason, the professor for my class decided to assign this problem in our Strings chapter and not in the Text I/O chapter (which is about 5 chapters later).

```
String sourceString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Test.txt")));
String formatted = sourceString.replaceAll("\\s\\{", "\\{");
System.out.println(formatted);
```

So that's what I have so far. When I do a run, the output is the same as the source file. I followed this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444199/reformatting-source-code-with-text-i-o) and using an idiom I found to convert all of the file into a String, the replaceAll method stopped... replacing.

While I still had it set up like this

```
StringBuilder source = new StringBuilder();
    while(s.hasNext()){
        source.append(s.nextLine());
    }
    String sourceString = source.toString();
    String formatted = sourceString.replaceAll("\\)\\s*\\{", ") {");
    System.out.println(formatted);
```

the output is all on a single line. I feel like the replaceAll method isn't occurring at all. I feel like I'm forgetting something blatantly obvious.

Comment: Basic check: does `nextLine` append the carriage return as well, or is it discarded automatically? If the latter, you need to add it yourself.

Comment: If I append it with s.nextLine() + "\r", the output becomes the same as my first attempt (using readAllBytes).

Comment: you regex is not working on multilines, you need `Pattern.DOTALL` for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of replaceAll() is a String, not a regex, so no need to escape the `{` there.

Also add a + to denote one or more whitespaces.

So:

```
sourceString.replaceAll("\\s+\\{", "{")
```

Comment: I get an invalid escape sequence if I use only one \.

Comment: I see my mistake now. I didn't bother editing the \\( out and I was only checking the first line of the output which did not contain a (. I changed it to your line and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without using `replaceAll()` and `regex` then try this one:

```
    String nextLine = null;
    String currentLine = null;
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        currentLine = s.nextLine();
        if (currentLine.trim().endsWith(")")) {
            while(s.hasNext()){
                if((nextLine = s.nextLine()).trim().length() != 0){
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (nextLine.trim().equals("{")) {
                source.append(currentLine).append(" {").append("\n");
            } else {
                source.append(currentLine).append("\n");
            }

        } else {
            source.append(currentLine).append("\n");
        }
    }
```